# Returning Array of Objects shows only one object in next step

Tags: zapier, zoho

Ive been working on a code zap step to make a get call to an api endpoint, and then transform the response into key pair objects to pass to further steps in zapier.

```js
var fileIds = [],
    tempData = [],
    newData = [],
    obj = [];



fetch('zoho getClientById endpoint'+inputData.id)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {

    tempData = json.response.result.Leads.row.FL;

    for(var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++ ){
      tempVal = tempData[i].val;
      newData = tempData[i].content;
      let allData = {};
      allData[tempVal] =  newData;
      obj.push(allData)

    }
    callback(null, obj);


  }).catch(callback);
```

Above is more or less the code Im using. It works, except that when the array of objects comes out of the step, only the first object is available for steps after. Im not certain if this is because of the way Im handling it, or if it's something with how zapier works.

Edit: What's interesting is I can use the log statement to see results in the meta data, and it shows the full array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a little extra reading, it seems that zapier will take each object in an array and try trigger another step with it. I updated my set up to just take the empty object I initially created and set a key with a value based off the value and content responses from my other response.